# Javascript on individual element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a written a little bit of javascript on my website, which fades in elements when they appear in the view. It's very inefficient though.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {


$('a.reposition.r1').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible) {
    $("a.reposition.r1").css({"opacity": "1", "transition": "1s"});
  } else {
    $("a.reposition.r1").css({"opacity": "0", "transition": "1s"});
  }

});

$('a.reposition.r2').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible) {
    $("a.reposition.r2").css({"opacity": "1", "transition": "1s"});
  } else {
    $("a.reposition.r2").css({"opacity": "0", "transition": "1s"});
  }

});

$('a.reposition.r3').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible) {
    $("a.reposition.r3").css({"opacity": "1", "transition": "1s"});
  } else {
    $("a.reposition.r3").css({"opacity": "0", "transition": "1s"});
  }

});


});
</script>
```

I tried to make it more compact, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('a.reposition').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
      if (visible) {
        $("a.reposition").css({"opacity": "1", "transition": "1s"});
      } else {
        $("a.reposition").css({"opacity": "0", "transition": "1s"});
      }

    });


</script>
```

But now *all* the elements fade in when the user scrolls the *first* element into the viewport. I want each element to fade in individually when the move into the viewport. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this` to get the current element that is being called

```
$('a.reposition').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible) {
    $(this).css({"opacity": "1", "transition": "1s"});
  } else {
    $(this).css({"opacity": "0", "transition": "1s"});
  }
});
```

and to get rid of the repeated code:

```
$('a.reposition').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
   var opacity = visible ? "1" : "0"; 
    $(this).css({"opacity": opacity, "transition": "1s"});
});
```